# Moving text from excel to inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm working on a project, which needs to put automatically some text from an excel into INKSCAPE.

[image: Example]

I want also to know if we can get the item list from inkscape: `Line`, `textbox`, `img` etc ...

Someone can give me some ideas or tips ?

Comment: Can you explain what those images are meant to tell us about your question?

Comment: @Moini the right array is our excel array, with different words. The left one is our INKSCAPE project, with some Lines/circles .. And what i want to do is to import the differents word from excel ( or a simple txt file ) into my inkscape project and automatically put them on the ligne/circles . thanks ^^

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the Generator Extension for Inkscape is what you need? It can place text into placeholders in your file, using a CSV file as data source.

More info and example file set linked from here: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Extension_repository#Generator